# How can a 2010 Publishing Page have a CustomizedPageStatus value of "Customized"?

Tags: 2010, publishing, variations, pages

I have a SharePoint 2010 Publishing Site Collection.  Out of the 1,000 or so publishing pages throughout the site collection, about a quarter of the pages have a CustomizedPageStatus of "Customized".

Other than disconnecting the Publishing Page from the Page Layout using SharePoint Designer, how would a publishing page have a CustomizedPageStatus of "Customized"?  Is it possible via content deployment (i.e. export/import of a Pages library from one farm to another)?

Note: we are using variations in this site collection and i see this mostly in pages in the variation labels (outside the variations root).  Perhaps the variations infrastructure is contributing to this?

Comment: What is the value of the Property, "vti_hasdefaultcontent", on the pages showing Customized?